# Tools to easily swap terraform versions

Tags: linux, terraform, terragrunt

I found the tools `tfenv` and `tfswitch` to easily and quickly change the terraform and terragrunt version - and I guess the tools work cause people use it, but for some reason they don't chagne the versions on my computer, after I run let's say

```sh
$ tfswitch 0.12.25
Downloading https://releases.hashicorp.com/terraform/0.12.25/terraform_0.12.25_darwin_amd64.zip to terraform_0.12.25_darwin_amd64.zip
Downloading ...
18220765 bytes downloaded.
Switched terraform to version "0.12.25"
```

It seems I correctly switch to version `0.12.25`, but after checking it with terraform it didin't change

```sh
$ terraform --version
Terraform v0.12.18
+ provider.google v3.29.0
+ provider.random v2.3.0

Your version of Terraform is out of date! The latest version
is 0.12.28. You can update by downloading from https://www.terraform.io/downloads.html
```

same goes for `tfenv` tool, anyone met with that problem ? I tried running it with sudo as well, but without success - I see the binaries are being downloaded to config dir of those tools and I even add them to PATH, but they don't overwrite the main `terraform` or `terragrunt` binaries that's why I'm left with the old versions, any thoughts ?

Comment: Sorry, but  StackOverflow is dedicated to helping solve programming code problems. If related to a production-level problem Your Q **may be**  more appropriate for [sf]  , but read their help section regarding on-topic questions . AND please read [Help On-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/On-topic) and [Help How-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/How-to-ask) before posting more Qs here.  Good luck.

Comment: Also, be sure to hover on the `teraform` tag at the bottom of your Q and read that information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem in the past, I solved it by removing the reference of Terraform from `.bash_profile` or `.zshrc` for zsh.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the exact same problem whilst using `tfswitch`

```
tfswitch 0.13.0
Installing terraform at /home/bin
Switched terraform to version "0.13.0"

terraform -v
Terraform v0.12.26
```

Terraform doesn't actually switch the versions and remains at `v0.12.26`

The answer provided on this post for removing the tf references located in `.bash_profile` doesn't appear to be working for me as the only reference to `$PATH` is the binaries for `tfswitch` for `/home/bin` which is required for it to work.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered with such a problem and fixed it by adding to ~/.zshrc or add to your ~/.bashrc :

```
export PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
```